# Using generated variable whose value was assigned in one function in another function

Tags: python-3.x, loops, variables, scope, global

New python amateur, and first time posting a question so excuse me if the structure of the question is not standard

**Full code**, if you understand what i am trying to achieve skip the intro, and skip the first four functions anyway (provided them if you want to execute the full code on your side):

```
import os, random
modes = ['Addition', 'Subtraction', 'Multiplication', 'Division']

global very_beginning, c_add, c_sub, c_mul, c_div, add_rounds, sub_rounds, mul_rounds, div_rounds, Round, correct, total_time

def mode_addition():
    num1, num2 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
    print(num1, " + ", num2)
    return num1 + num2


def mode_subtraction():
    num1, num2 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
    while num1 <= num2:
        num1, num2 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
    print(num1, " - ", num2)
    return num1 - num2


def mode_multiplication():
    num1, num2 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
    print(num1, " X ", num2)
    return num1 * num2


def mode_division():
    num2, num3 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
    num1 = num2 * num3
    print(num1, " ÷ ", num2)
    return num3


def mode_var_names(mode):
    return "mode_" + mode.lower() + "()", "c_" + mode.lower()[0:3], mode.lower()[0:3] + "_rounds"

def mental_math():
    print("Mental math game: ")
    global Round, correct, total_time, c_add, c_sub, c_mul, c_div, add_rounds, sub_rounds, mul_rounds, div_rounds
    Round, total_time = 1, 0
    correct, c_add, c_sub, c_mul, c_div, add_rounds, sub_rounds, mul_rounds, div_rounds = int(), int(), int(), int(), int(), int(), int(), int(), int()
    while Round <= 20:
        print('Round ' + str(Round), end=":\n\n")
        roundmode = random.choice(modes)
        mode_info = mode_var_names(roundmode)
        print("This round will be about:", roundmode)
        correct_answer = eval(mode_info[0])
        exec(mode_info[2] + " += 1")
        print("The answer is: ", end='')
        roundanswer = int(input())
        if roundanswer == correct_answer:
            print("The answer {} is correct.".format(roundanswer))
            correct += 1
            exec(mode_info[1] + " += 1")
        else:
            print("The answer {} is incorrect. The answer should be: {}".format(roundanswer, correct_answer))
        print("You got {} out of {} questions correct".format(correct, Round))
        user = input("Press enter to continue, or type 'stop' to end this quiz\n")
        if user == 'stop' or Round == 20:
            result_page()
            break
        Round += 1

def result_page():
    mark = round(correct / Round * 100)
    os.system('cls')
    print("Mental math game")
    print('FIN\n\n')
    print("You solved {} questions".format(Round))
    print("You got {}% of the questions correct.".format(mark))
    print("If you want detailed results type 'details'")
    print("If you want to continue, type 'again', else just close this windows or press Enter")
    user = input()
    if user == "details":
    for i in modes:
        print("In", i, "You got ", eval(mode_var_names(i)[1]), "correct answers out of ",
              eval(mode_var_names(i)[2]))

mental_math()
```

**Intro**:

I am putting together a mental math game as coding practice. It randomly chooses the mode from a list of strings: ['Addition', 'Subtraction', 'Multiplication' and 'Division'],uses its name to call the corresponding function which creates the question (for example if it chose Addition it would call a function called mode_addition)and keeps track of the number of correct answers of each mode out of the total of each mode as variables generated on the spot with a predetermined template (for example if it chose addition it would create 2 variables called c_add (stores correct answer) and add_rounds (stores total rounds/questions involving addition) as follows:

```
modes = ['Addition', 'Subtraction', 'Multiplication', 'Division']
def mode_var_names(mode):
    return "mode_" + mode.lower() + "()", "c_" + mode.lower()[0:3], mode.lower()[0:3] + "_rounds" 
roundmode = random.choice(modes)
mode_info = mode_var_names(roundmode)
```

> the return keyword returns a string containing the variable name which
>   is then incremented through exec function
>
> ex: exec(mode_info[1] + " += 1") increments the c_add if mode is
>   addition

I broke up the app into 2 main functions, the main one called mental_math (which contains the above code and generates the variables) and another one called results_page (which is called once I type in 'stop' at the interpreter or solve 20 questions) to show the percentage and how many questions of each mode have i got correctly.

**Now the problem**:

I am trying to get the variables generated at the mental_math to print their values at the results_page through the following code :

```
for i in modes:
    print("In", i, "You got ", eval(mode_var_names(i)[1]), "correct answers out of ",
        eval(mode_var_names(i)[2]))
```

And both the correct and the total of all the round return 0:

```
In Addition You got  0 correct answers out of  0
In Subtraction You got  0 correct answers out of  0
In Multiplication You got  0 correct answers out of  0
In Division You got  0 correct answers out of  0
```

, while the percentage "mark = round(correct / Round * 100)" is correct. When i copy the print loop back to the mental_math i get the correct numbers ( but still i want to know why the original state doesn't work)

**What i tried so far**

the global keyword thrown around is a failed attempt to get the results_page to get the modes' variables (but do the job for Round and correct variables), and i can't pass the eval() code used to generate the variables' names directly to global , i thought of using return method but don't know how to use it in this context (and would rather just make the generated variables accessible)

I also tried grouping them together as a class hoping all variables would be accessible to other functions or an instance but failed because i am just starting to learn OOP

**Update & Solution**:

There are (at least) 2 fixes, the answer Jason Nick Porter, and adding the 2 functions to the same class

Comment: I chose to generate the variables as a practice to this technique as an alternative to very long nested conditionals in other applications with much more "modes"

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: The first block was the entire code (minus some unrelated features) so that whoever wants to get my results and tinker with the app can do so no additional effort,the second block was some explanation of the method, the other 2 blocks have the specific code related to the issue and the result (which i do not want to see), should i remove the first block? or what exactly should i remove?

Comment: Anything you need to do to make it [mcve]. If that means removing those codes, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I ended up editing this a lot, so it gets increasingly correct as you go along :)

I would start by ditching the globals at the top. Global variables are a fickle mistress, one that I try to avoid at all costs. This would be a great place to use an array in your `mental_math()` fcn. Inside the function where you currently have:

```
global Round, correct, total_time, c_add, c_sub, c_mul, c_div, add_rounds, sub_rounds, mul_rounds, div_rounds
Round, total_time = 1, 0
correct, c_add, c_sub, c_mul, c_div, add_rounds, sub_rounds, mul_rounds, div_rounds = int(), int(), int(), int(), int(), int(), int(), int(), int()
```

I would just put:

```
level, total_time = [1,0] # I put level instead of Round, since round is a keyword and could be confusing
correct = [0,0,0,0] # the index here corresponds to the mode
asked = [0,0,0,0]   # numpy.zeros would be an even more robust way to do this
```

So that each variable exists within the function, and then at the end of `mental_math()` have something like this:

```
if user == 'stop' or level == 20:
    stats = [level, correct, total_time ] # and all the rest...
    result_page(stats)
    break
```

Then all the stats you have are passed to the `results_page()`. Now you'll want to make the modes into tuples instead of strings at the top of your program. Tuples are basically the best, because you can link together different types of variables, like so:

```
modes = [('Addition'       , 3 , 7), # These numbers correspond to where the correct
         ('Subtraction'    , 4 , 8), # and total numbers will be located in the stats
         ('Multiplication' , 5 , 9), # array.
         ('Division'       , 6 , 10)] # The spacing just makes it easier to see
```

Now you'll have to adjust `results_page()` to receive the array. Then instead of each variable name, you can access all the values by their index. Like so:

```
def result_page(stats):
    mark = round(correct / stats[0] * 100)
    os.system('cls')
    print("Mental math game")
    print('FIN\n\n')
    print("You solved {} questions".format(stats[0]))
    print("You got {}% of the questions correct.".format(mark))
    print("If you want detailed results type 'details'")
    user = input("If you want to continue, type 'again', else just close this window or press Enter")
    # Fun-fact: If you pass a string to input() it prints it as a prompt
    if user == "details":
    for i in modes:
        print("In", i[0], " you got ", stats[i[1]], " correct answers out of ",
              stats[i[2]])
```

Then you don't even need `mode_var_names()`.

## EDIT:

Ok I didn't realize some of the problems with my code, so some of the above is not great. I'm leaving it there in case it's helpful though.

The code below is updated and should let you add as many modes as you want. The problem was that I didn't look closely at `mental_math()`, so I didn't realize it was still calling `mode_var_names()`. Now instead of executing a function with a variable string, it just passes an int to a single function, and uses the same int to decide which numbers to update in the "correct" and "asked" arrays.

```
import os
import random
import numpy as np

modes = [('Addition'       , 3 , 7), # These numbers correspond to where the correct
         ('Subtraction'    , 4 , 8), # and total numbers will be located in the stats
         ('Multiplication' , 5 , 9), # array.
         ('Division'       , 6 , 10)] # The spacing just makes it easier to see


def process(mode):
    # if you have more modes you want to add, just add more elif statements
    if mode == 0:
        num1, num2 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
        print(num1, " + ", num2)
        return num1 + num2
    
    elif mode == 1:
        num1, num2 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
        while num1 <= num2:
            num1, num2 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
        print(num1, " - ", num2)
        return num1 - num2
    
    elif mode == 2:
        num1, num2 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
        print(num1, " X ", num2)
        return num1 * num2

    elif mode == 3:
        num2, num3 = random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)
        num1 = num2 * num3
        print(num1, " ÷ ", num2)
        return num3

def mental_math():
    print("Mental math game: ")
    level, total_time = 0,0 # I put level instead of level, since level is a keyword and could be confusing
    
    correct = np.zeros(len(modes)) # the index here corresponds to the mode
    asked = np.zeros(len(modes))
    
    while level <= 20:
        level += 1
        print('Round ' + str(level), end=":\n\n")
        m = random.choice(range(len(modes)))
        print("This level will be about:", modes[m][0])
        
        correct_answer = process(m)
        asked[m] += 1
        
        levelanswer = int(input("The answer is: "))
        
        if levelanswer == correct_answer:
            print("The answer {} is correct.".format(levelanswer))
            correct[m] += 1
        else:
            print("The answer {} is incorrect. The answer should be: {}".format(levelanswer, correct_answer))
            
        print("You got {} out of {} questions correct".format(sum(correct), level))
        user = input("Press enter to continue, or type 'stop' to end this quiz\n")
        if user == 'stop' or level == 20:
            stats = np.hstack((level,sum(correct),total_time,correct,asked))
            result_page(stats)
            break
        

def result_page(stats):
    mark = round(stats[1] / stats[0] * 100)
    os.system('cls')
    print("Mental math game")
    print('FIN\n\n')
    print("You solved {} questions".format(stats[0]))
    print("You got {}% of the questions correct.".format(mark))
    print("If you want detailed results type 'details'")
    user = input("If you want to continue, type 'again', else just close this window or press Enter\n")
    if user == "details":
        for i in modes:
            print("In", i[0], " you got ", stats[i[1]], " correct answers out of ",
                  stats[i[2]])

mental_math()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, I originally wanted to use the mode_var_names() to cut down on using many conditionals depending on the random mode chosen, but to keep an open mind i tried your way and I am facing a couple of difficulties applying your changes: 1) How are you incrementing the counters of the 4 modes, are you using 4 conditionals? 2) How are you modifying the tuples in the 'modes' list to the updated counters? If you have written a complete script would you mind sharing it?

Comment: Oh you're right, this is more complicated than I anticipated... Give me a little bit to update my response :)

Comment: @yousefmohamed I've updated my response and included the complete code. As a general rule, read through the code carefully and make sure you understand why each line is there. That way you can edit, recreate, and improve it; I'm sure you'll need to do all three!

Comment: Now it works. Thanks! However since i haven't yet learned numpy i wasn't able to completely follow what you have done but i will return back to it once i have learned numpy. For now made an alternative vesion where I added both functions to a class and results_page accessed the c_add/add_rounds etc.... without using global, so problem solved